# Indexing numpy.ndarrays periodically

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to access (read/write) `numpy.ndarrays` periodically. In other words, if I have `my_array` with the shape of **10*10** and I use the access operator with the inputs:

`my_arrray[10, 10]` or `acess_function(my_array, 10, 10)`

I can have access to element

`my_array[0, 0]`.

I want to have read/write ability at my returned element of periodically indexed array.

Can anyone how to do it without making a shifted copy of my original array?

Comment: `my_array[0:10:2, :]` will access every second row in a 10x10 2d array.  It can be used in calculations (read) or can be used on the left hand side of an assignment (write).  [Slicing and indexing docs here.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html).  Is this what you mean by periodic?

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I did not mean accessing in every nth row as periodic. My question was referring the situation in which if I use the access operator with inputs bigger than size of my array lets say my array is **NxN** and I call the access operator with [N+p, N+q] it gives me the [p, q] th element of tthe array. I came up with the idea of using residual of deviding the input of access operator by the size for this end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want but I'm not sure whether there's something more elegant that exists.  It's probably possible to write a general function for an Nd array but this does 2D only.  As you said it uses modular arithmetic.

```
import numpy as np

def access(shape, ixr, ixc):
    """ Returns a selection. """
    return np.s_[ixr % shape[0], ixc % shape[1]]

arr = np.arange(100)
arr.shape = 10,10

arr[ access(arr.shape, 45, 87) ]
# 57

arr[access(arr.shape, 45, 87)] = 100

In [18]: arr 
# array([[  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9],
#        [ 10,  11,  12,  13,  14,  15,  16,  17,  18,  19],
#        [ 20,  21,  22,  23,  24,  25,  26,  27,  28,  29],
#        [ 30,  31,  32,  33,  34,  35,  36,  37,  38,  39],
#        [ 40,  41,  42,  43,  44,  45,  46,  47,  48,  49],
#        [ 50,  51,  52,  53,  54,  55,  56, **100**,  58,  59],
#        [ 60,  61,  62,  63,  64,  65,  66,  67,  68,  69],
#        [ 70,  71,  72,  73,  74,  75,  76,  77,  78,  79],
#        [ 80,  81,  82,  83,  84,  85,  86,  87,  88,  89],
#        [ 90,  91,  92,  93,  94,  95,  96,  97,  98,  99]])
```

**Edit - Generic nD version**

```
def access(shape, *args):
    if len(shape) != len(args):
        error = 'Inconsistent number of dimemsions: {} & number of indices: {} in coords.'
        raise IndexError( error.format(len(shape), len(args)))
    res = []
    for limit, ix in zip(shape, args):
        res.append(ix % limit)
    return tuple(res)
```

Usage/Test

```
a = np.arange(24)
a.shape = 2,3,4
a[access(a.shape, 5, 6, 7)]
# 15

a[access(a.shape, 5,6,7) ] = 100
a
# array([[[  0,   1,   2,   3],
#         [  4,   5,   6,   7],
#         [  8,   9,  10,  11]],
#        [[ 12,  13,  14, 100],
#         [ 16,  17,  18,  19],
#         [ 20,  21,  22,  23]]])
```

Comment: @afalsafi.  I've added an nd array version.  It may help